# Export query result to csv in UTF-8

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bcp

I would like to export query result to csv file in utf-8. Now i export to csv in this way:

```
    DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
    SET @cmd = 'bcp "select * from table" queryout "d:\textfile.csv" -w -T -t; -Slocalhost'
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

How to make file be in UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support code page 65001 (UTF-8 encoding). [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

You need to add `-w` parameter in bcp utility to specify the encoding is `UTF16`.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure you have long since solved your problem but as this is still open thought it might help someone else.

I am creating txt files with SQL Server queries and they seem to be "plain ANSI". In the end I used iconv.exe to convert from WINDOWS-1252 to UTF-8

iconv.exe is part of the GnuWin package which can be downloaded from Sourceforge https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/